# NEO4j: Causal Cluster in different hosts

Tags: docker, neo4j

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/clustering/

---

Variation to documented NEO4J sample below gives me output like
`Waiting for a total of 3 core members...`

```
docker run --name=neo4j-core \
         --network=host \
         --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
         --publish=5000:5000 --publish=6000:6000 --publish=7000:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_expected__core__cluster__size=3 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=ec2_ip_1:5000,ec2_ip_2:5000,ec2_ip_3:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_discovery__advertised__address=ec2_ip_1:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_transaction__advertised__address=ec2_ip_1:6000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_raft__advertised__address=ec2_ip_1:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connectors_default__advertised__address=ec2_ip_1 \
         --env NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=ec2_ip_1:7687 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=ec2_ip_1:7474 \
         neo4j:3.5-enterprise

docker run --name=neo4j-core \
         --network=host \
         --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
         --publish=5000:5000 --publish=6000:6000 --publish=7000:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_expected__core__cluster__size=3 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=ec2_ip_1:5000,ec2_ip_2:5000,ec2_ip_3:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_discovery__advertised__address=ec2_ip_2:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_transaction__advertised__address=ec2_ip_2:6000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_raft__advertised__address=ec2_ip_2:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connectors_default__advertised__address=ec2_ip_2 \
         --env NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=ec2_ip_2:7687 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=ec2_ip_2:7474 \
         neo4j:3.5-enterprise

docker run --name=neo4j-core \
         --network=host \
         --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
         --publish=5000:5000 --publish=6000:6000 --publish=7000:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_expected__core__cluster__size=3 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=ec2_ip_1:5000,ec2_ip_2:5000,ec2_ip_3:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_discovery__advertised__address=ec2_ip_3:5000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_transaction__advertised__address=ec2_ip_3:6000 \
         --env NEO4J_causal__clustering_raft__advertised__address=ec2_ip_3:7000 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connectors_default__advertised__address=ec2_ip_3 \
         --env NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=ec2_ip_3:7687 \
         --env NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address=ec2_ip_3:7474 \
         neo4j:3.5-enterprise
```

UPDATE: For this to work in EC2 instances I had to use a Private IP (instead of the NEO4j documented Public IP)

Comment: For this to work in EC2 instances I had to use a Private IP (instead of the NEO4j documented Public IP)